# Convert HTML to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio

I have an app written with react.js and I want to sent a encode base 64 HTML to an android device.
The android device must decode and change the HTML code to bitmap. I can not figure out that part( convert HTML to bitmap ); Can anyone help me? I am trying with webview right now but the webview doesn't take the data from html.

```
WebView webview = New WebView(getApplicationContext());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64", "");
shareResultAsImage(webview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView's onDraw() method to obtain the image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(...);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
webView.onDraw(canvas);
```

Comment: even if I go with canvas i need my webView to have data. right now i can not add data To webView .   webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=file:///android_asset/test.html"); even like this my webView did not take any data

Comment: Why do you need docs.google.com to open a file in assets? It will not work for sure. Use webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");